# Include the soft keyboard in XML layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-softkeyboard

I want to include the Android system's soft keyboard in my custom layout.

Example:

```
<include
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  layout="@layout/android.soft_keyboard" /> <!-- what to put this line to reference to system keyboard? -->
```

Note: I already knew how to programatically call the soft keyboard. In this  case, I just want to call it in my XML.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to include the Android system's soft keyboard in my custom layout.

That is not possible. There is no single "Android system's soft keyboard", as devices routinely ship their own. That input method editor is from another app, not yours. And, there is no requirement for the input method editor to use a layout.